# Fill "n" memory locations in Assembler

Tags: assembly, nand2tetris

I'm trying to do the job, but I can't. Can anyone help me and explain how to make the assignment: "fill n memory locations from address  with value -1" // R1 <- n
// R2 <- addr

Comment: Google "memset" for whatever ISA this is and look for simple non-optimized example implementations.  Many different ISAs have registers called R1 and R2, including at least ARM, MSP430, and LC-3.

Comment: Which architecture and assembler are you programming for?

Comment: it is some example about nand2tetris

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help me and explain how to make the assignment:

The idea is to pick apart the problem and solve pieces, then put the pieces together into an overall solution.

In no particular order:

---

An algorithm for setting memory, in C:

```
int R1;
int *R2;
do {
    *R2++ = -1;
} while ( --R1 >= 0 );
```

You don't have to think in assembly language to come up with an algorithm.  Much easier to do in a language you know then take pieces of that into assembly.

---

You will need to do memory writes.

Memory writes are performed by doing an `M=` instruction, such as `M=D`.  That operation will do `Memory[A]=D` — so you need a memory address in the `A` register and a value to store in the `D` register before performing this operation.

---

You're told to put the values at the location referred to by `R2`, so fetch the value of variable in `R2` and put it into the `A` register.  `R2` is an alias for data memory location 2, so here, `R2` is a pointer variable that lives in memory.

```
@R2     // put 2 in `A`
A=M     // fetch from Memory[A] and put the result back into A
```

---

You're told to use -1 to fill the memory, so put a -1 in `D`.  We can do this directly in a C-instruction, so don't need an `@` instruction to load the -1:

```
D=-1     // set D to -1
```

With the above setup, you can do an `M=D` to fill one memory location with -1.

---

To store at successive locations, you'll need to increment the pointer in `R2`.

---

You will need a counted loop.

Since the other registers (`A`, `D`) will be busy doing things inside the loop the counter will have to be located somewhere in memory.  And you're told that the counter is in `R1` — the same as `Memory[1]`.

You can decrement the counter with a simple sequence as follows:

```
@R1      // put 1, the memory address of R1, in A
M=M-1    // instruction the machine to decrement memory
```

However, if you want to also want to also test the counter, bring the counter into the `D` register as well as storing it back to memory and add a backward conditional branch to continue the loop:

```
(loop1)   // define top of loop
...       // body of loop
@R1       // target the counter (A=&counter)
MD=M-1    // compute counter-1, store back to memory &counter, and keep copy in D
@loop1    // target the loop top (A=&loop)
D;JGE     // branch to repeat the loop if D >= 0
```

This will accomplish, for example:

```
do {
    ...
} while ( --counter >= 0 )
```

Comment: so this is answer ?  >(loop1)   // define top of loop
...       // body of loop
ATR1       // target the counter (A=&counter)
MD=M-1    // compute counter-1, store back to memory &counter, and keep copy in D
ATloop1    // target the loop top (A=&loop)
D;JGE     // branch to repeat the loop if D >= 0

Comment: You asked if someone can explain how to do it.  My answer describe the "how" that you've asked about.  You can apply this as you write your solution to the assignment.